# How to add weights into sack by taking 2 items at a time in an array?

Tags: c, arrays

Find the total weight in the sack in such a way that at each time we need to pick only 2 items from the array and add to the sack.

**Inputs:**

```
int n = 5;
int w = {1 3 7 5 6};
```

- The Items with weight 1 and 3 are added → 4(A).
- Then A and item with weight 5 are added → 9(B).
- After that item with weights 6 and 7 are added → 13(C).
- Last B and C are added → 22
- `totalweight=4(A)+9(B)+13(C)+22`

**MyLogic:**

```
int totalweight(int n, int w[]){
   int x = w[0] + w[1];
   int t = x;
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
   {
    sum = sum + t;
    t = w[i] + t;
   }

  return sum;
 }
```

**My Output:**

```
31
```

**Expected Output:**

```
48
```

I am adding subsequently. How do I fix this?

Comment: It doesn't seem clear how your algorithm works. Why did you choose to add B and C at the end? And how come A and 5 were added in line two?

Comment: you are given multiple ingredients  and you know their weight. you have to mix all the ingredients(in any order) two at a time and the time for each mixing order will be sum of their weights. you have to mix the ingredients in such a way that the total time is minimum. you have to return the total weight

Comment: How is adding `A` with `5` taking two items from the array? (never-mind it is a "Pick and Add to the Array" type deal)

Comment: in general, to obtain the minimum time, Suggest taking the sum of the lowest available weight Plus the highest available weight.  Then those two weights are not available anymore

Comment: @mike I edited my answer to now where I believe it answers your question better. Can you confirm that the edit applies to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

After rereading your comment, I believe this is more of an algorithm question. And if so, I would recommend using a linked list data structure approach instead. Imagine your array as a linked list,

```
1->3->5->6->7
```

I sorted it primarily because your goal is to find the smallest total possible. Then keep doing this algorithm below until there is only one element in your linked list left.

1. Add the first two elements in your linked list
2. Remove the first two elements from the linked list but keep track of
   this local sum
3. Add that local sum to a global sum variable
4. Store the local sum in the linked list while keeping the list sorted
5. Repeat until there is only one element left in the linked list

Here is an example of the list after each iteration of this algorithm,

```
1->3->5->6->7, sum = 0
4->5->6->7, sum = 0 + 4 = 4
6->7->9, sum = 4 + 9 = 13
9->13, sum = 13 + 13 = 26
22, sum = 26 + 22 = 48
```

I will leave the coding up to you as it can get quite involved to code a linked list and a function to keep it sorted every time an element is added. However, to get you started here's an example of how to add an element to a linked list,

```
struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node *next; 
};

void addToTheEnd(Node** head, int value) {
    //adds an element to the end of a linked list
    if(*head == NULL) {
        *head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        (*head)->data = value;
        (*head)->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        struct Node* current = *head;
        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        current->next->data = value;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
}
```